# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "G" OJDBC7 apache camel

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, ojdbc

This is happening in select query..

none of the column starts with 'G' nor any table alias name also starts with it.
SQL query is not updated since 6 months.

only change is that we have upgraded to OJDBC7 jar. Earlier working fine for OJDBC6 jar.

Comment: Can you add the query and the whole actual error message? Are you sure you're looking at the *right* query?

Comment: Yes, checked several times,

Comment: 'ORA-00904: "LINE_IDNDM"."HIDDEN_NAME": invalid identifier
 Query: select distinct s.ID as key, count(*) as value  from EMP ed, dept s, channel_maps cm, line l, account c  where ed.DEPT_ID = s.DEPT_ID and s.DEPT_ID = cm.DEPT_ID  and cm.LINE_ID = l.LINE_ID AND CM.HIDDEN_NAME=0 and l.ACCOUNT_ID = c.ACCOUNT_ID  and l.NAT_LINE_ID = ? and c.NAT_ACCOUNT_ID = ? group by s.ID Parameters: [37, 29] at org.apache.commons.dbutils.AbstractQueryRunner.rethrow(AbstractQueryRunner.java:392)
        at org.apache.commons.dbutils.QueryRunner.query(QueryRunner.java:351)
        at org.apache.commons.dbuti

Comment: So it's losing characters from the statement!? Is the driver you're using compatible with your DB version?

Comment: not loosing but adding extra characters. IDNDM getting added. Looks like there is compatibility issue oracle11.2 & jdbc7. Is this compatibility real issue? because all other several queries are working fine. Only 2 failing out of 50.

Comment: I think `l.LINE_ID AND CM.HIDDEN_NAME` is being contracted to `LINE_IDNDM.HIDDEN_NAME`? Anyway...

Comment: ah got the issue, oracle version is not compatible with ojdbc version. thanks Alex appreciate you help!